# ggplot2 add two plots in grid.arrange with an inset in the second one in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, insets

I'm able to print an inset and to create a grid from plots in ggplots. But I'm not able to create a grid with a plot on the left and 2 plots on the right one full size and the other in "inset".

```
a_plot <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_line()

#The inset 
print(a_plot);print(a_plot, vp = vp)
```

[image]

```
# the Grid
lay <- rbind(c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
             c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
             c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
             c(1,1,1,2,2,2))
grid.arrange(a_plot, a_plot,layout_matrix = lay)
```

[image]

But I would like to have this:

[image]

How can I do this?

This doesn't work

```
grid.arrange(a_plot, a_plot,print(a_plot, vp = vp),layout_matrix = lay)
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305106/in-r-how-can-i-store-an-inset-graph-for-later-arranging-it-with-grid-arrange?rq=1) and it didn't work either.

Comment: I'm able to use this to create an inset but not to put it on a grid after that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a_plot <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_line()
b_plot <- a_plot + annotation_custom(grob = rectGrob(), 
                      xmin = 15, xmax = Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=25)


grid.arrange(a_plot, b_plot, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: b_plot <- a_plot+coord_cartesian() + annotation_custom(grob = ggplotGrob(a_plot), xmin = -90.2, xmax = Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=-0.8)

`coord_cartesian()` might be needed if the object is a map. Instead of `reacGrob()`, use `ggplotGrob()`